# How to iterate through a table and use column attributes to make a line in postGIS

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, postgis

Say I have a table:

```
ID    X    Y   TIME
---------------------
A     1    2     0
B     9    5     0
A     2    3     1
C     0    0     3
B     9    6     1
B     10   6     2
C     1    0     5
A     2    9     11
...
```

I want to be able to make lines such that I have:

```
ID    LINE
A     (1,2) -> (2,9)
B     (9,5) -> (10, 6)
C     (0,0) -> (1, 0)
```

So, we make points from earliest start time to latest finish time for each ID.

How could I write PostGIS SQL to do this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand you want to create a straight line between first and last point for each id. If it is correct then:

```
with pr as(select id, x, y, 
                  row_number() over (partition by id order by time, (x,y)) rnk_asc, 
                  row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc,(x,y)) rnk_desc
             from points)

select pr.id, st_makeline(st_point(pr.x, pr.y) , st_point(pr2.x, pr2.y))
  from pr, pr pr2
 where pr.id=pr2.id
   and pr.rnk_asc=1
   and pr2.rnk_desc=1
```

A little code explanation:

- I called your table "points"
- I use "with" statement to make code clearer and it a bit faster than doing it two times in "from" part of normal select
- row_number() is a window function you can read more in postgres docs about it. I just use it to rank rows  and find first and last one
- st_point is postgis function for creating postgis point object from x and y (lat and long)
- st_makeline is postgis function for creating line between two points

I hope it will help you.
If you will have a big amount of data to transform give me a sign I can give you a few tips to make it much faster then this simple SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not eloquent in PostGIS SQL, so I might be wrong here, but in SQL in general you need to do something like this:

```
insert into SecondTable(ID, LINE)
select ID, as LINE 
from FirstTable l
join FirstTable r
on l.ID = r.ID
where
not exists (select ID
            from FirstTable aux
            where aux.TIME < l.TIME or aux.TIME > r.TIME) and
not exists (select ID
            from SecondTable
            where l.ID = SecondTable.ID);
```